# Entire function constant with special properties

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function.Also $f(z)/z\rightarrow 0$ as $|z|\rightarrow \infty$.Show that $f$ is constant

My attempt:I was thinking of using Liouville's theorem on $g(z)=f(z)/z$.Is the approach right?

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. $f(z)/z$ is not an entire function, unless $f(0)=0$. But $(f(z)-f(0))/z$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

As an alternative, use Cauchy's inequality. Given $\epsilon>0$ there is an $R$ such that 
$$
|z|\ge R \implies |f(z)|\le\epsilon\,|z|.
$$
Then for all $r>R$ and $n\ge0$
$$
\frac{|f^{(n)}(0)|}{n!}\le\frac{1}{2\,\pi}\Bigl|\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}}\,d\,\zeta\Bigr|\le\epsilon\,r^{n-1}.
$$
Now consider separately the cases $n=1$ and $n>1$.

Comment: But how to conclude from here?

Comment: For the first approach: apply Liouville's theorem to $(f(z)-f(0))/z$. For the second: let $r\to\infty$ and deduce that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ if $n\ge1$.